# Questions about getting logged in user's picture using Graph API (iOS)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ios5, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to get the logged in user's pictures (Not profile pictures, but pictures from albums). So I figured I would use

```
[facebookInstance requestWithGraphPath:@"me/albums" andDelegate:self];
```

However the result object obtained is empty.

```
 (gdb) po result
 {
     data =     (
     );
 }
```

I also tried

```
[facebookInstance requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" andDelegate:self];
```

but I still got the same results. So I was wondering if there is something wrong I am doring with permissions? The permission I have right now is "read_stream". I hope this should be good enough, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I did not read the documents correctly. I do require "user_photos" permission. Now it works!